# where is the cpp-package in mxnet 1.6?

Tags: c++, mxnet

I tried to compile lates mxnet from git but there is no cpp-package as in before in 1.5 ?
How can I use c++ api in latest mxnet. ?

I compiled as n described and tis not produced op.h

Comment: https://mxnet.apache.org/versions/1.6/get_started/cpp_setup?

Comment: Please edit your question with the exact steps you took to compile MXNet and what errors you got when you tried to compile.